# Where can I find information on a given pan's bottom diameter?

Tags: cookware, pan

I am currently looking for a small pan. I measured the plate (ceramic) where it would be used (15 cm) and started looking for 15 cm pans online with little success. So far I've discovered that the advertised measurement for a pan typically refers to the *upper diameter* of the pan, not to that of the cooking surface, but that takes me back to square 1: **how to know whether the pan will fit on the designed plate?**

Where can I find this information, when it is missing from the product description?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to find a question in your post. You have already recognized that the metric you are looking for is not publicly available. Can you formulate exactly what you want to know? Please note that our site does not take questions about the business decisions of sellers, so "why don't they mark their pans by the bottom diameter" is a question we would close.

Comment: I agree that the question is very open ended, but I think @Johanna's answer goes in the right direction: the missing information is relevant to make a purchase decision and I was hoping to find tips to get around the fact that it is not explicit. I can imagine many types of answers (e.g. "a couple of cms of difference are fine", "you can find measurements for common models at <insert URL>", "rule of thumb: bottom diameter = top diameter - 2 cm"). 

My question is ultimately: **how do I make an informed purchase with the information I have so that I don't have to return the pan afterwards?**

Comment: Hi Sergio, thank you for clearing that up! If you were to ask "is it OK for the pan to not fit the plate" or "how much difference is acceptable", the question would have to stay closed, since this is a subjective question. If you are looking to purchase a pan that fits, we have to assume that for you personally, you expect that your pan fits. Also, the question "how to make an informed decision" is trivially, you don't. So I edited it to match the third possible question I gleaned from your comment, where to find more information, and reopened.